# AzureDevOps Multistage build and release pipeline variable sharing

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-multistage-pipeline

What am I doing wrong? I've got a multistage build and release pipeline that works in the following way

Build > release to UAT > release to UAT 2 (our prod)  but I'm just playing around to get it working

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: 'Build'
    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    jobs:
      - job: Build                  
        steps: 
          - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
            displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.x'
            inputs:
              versionSpec: 5.x
      
          - task: NuGetCommand@2
            displayName: 'NuGet restore'
            inputs:
              restoreSolution: '**/*.sln' 

          - task: VSBuild@1
            displayName: 'Build solution'
            inputs:
              solution: '$(solution)'
              msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\\"'
              platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
              configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

          - task: PublishSymbols@2
            displayName: 'Publish symbols path'
            inputs:
              SearchPattern: '**\bin\**\*.pdb'
              PublishSymbols: false
            continueOnError: true

          - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
            displayName: 'Publish Artifact'
            inputs:
              PathtoPublish: '$(build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
              ArtifactName: 'drop'

  - stage: UAT
    displayName: 'UAT'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'))
    dependsOn: Build

    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployApp
        pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-latest'
        displayName: 'Release artefacts to Test-Evn (Zip)'
        environment: 'test-env'
       
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
                displayName: 'Download Artifacts (drop)'
                inputs:
                  buildType: 'current'
                  artifactName: 'drop'
                  targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

              - task: PowerShell@2
                condition: and(succeeded(), not(canceled()))
                name: RetainOnSuccess
                displayName: Retain on Success
                inputs:
                  failOnStderr: true
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    $contentType = "application/json";
                    $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
                    $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 365; definitionId = $(System.DefinitionId); ownerId = 'User:$(Build.RequestedForId)'; protectPipeline = $false; runId = $(Build.BuildId) };
                    $request = ConvertTo-Json @($rawRequest);
                    $uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases?api-version=6.0-preview.1";
                    $newLease = Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
                    $newLeaseId = $newLease.Value[0].LeaseId
                    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=newLeaseId;isOutput=true]$newLeaseId";
     
              - script: echo $(RetainOnSuccess.newLeaseId)
                name: echovar

  - stage: UAT2
    displayName: 'UAT2'
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master'))
    dependsOn: UAT
     
    jobs:
      - deployment: DeployApp
        pool:
          vmImage: 'windows-latest'
        displayName: 'Release artefacts to TestEnv2 (Zip)'
        environment: 'test-env-2'
        variables:
        - name: NewLeaseId
          value: $[ dependencies.UAT.outputs['DeployApp.RetainOnSuccess.newLeaseId']]

        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
              - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
                displayName: 'Download Artifacts (drop)'
                inputs:
                  buildType: 'current'
                  artifactName: 'drop'
                  targetPath: '$(System.ArtifactsDirectory)'

              - script: echo "https://dev.azure.com/testing-ci/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/$(NewLeaseId)?api-version=6.1-preview.2"

              - task: PowerShell@2
                condition: and(succeeded(), not(canceled()))
                name: RetainOnSuccess
                displayName: Retain on Success
                inputs:
                  failOnStderr: true
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    $contentType = "application/json";
                    $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
                    $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 365 * 100; leaseId = $newLeaseId; ownerId = 'User:$(Build.RequestedForId)' };
                    $request = ConvertTo-Json @($rawRequest);
                    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/testing-ci/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/$(NewLeaseId)?api-version=6.1-preview.2";
                    Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method PATCH -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
```

I'm trying to update the retention lock as per documentation

If a release gets put to UAt then apply a lock for a year
If a release gets to prod then update that retention indef

the error I'm getting is:

```
[error]Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'PATCH'."}}
```

That's because its missing the value of the variable and therefore the url that its trying to patch to is

[https://dev.azure.com/testing-ci/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/?api-version=6.1-preview.2"](https://dev.azure.com/testing-ci/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/?api-version=6.1-preview.2%22)

It's missing the value of $(NewLeaseId)

Comment: This is most likely a compile-time vs runtime variable resolution issue. The inline powershell script is emitted into the final YAML document long before your runtime variable can be resolved. Did you try passing the runtime value into the script via an `env` block, then accessing it within your script as `$env:NewLeaseId`?

Comment: Brilliant, that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

`$[ dependencies.UAT.DeployApp.outputs['RetainOnSuccess.newLeaseId'] ]`