# Devops Retention PATCH Failing

Tags: azure-devops

Follow on from

[AzureDevOps Multistage build and release pipeline variable sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255035/azuredevops-multistage-build-and-release-pipeline-variable-sharing?noredirect=1#comment129376601_73255035)

I've managed to get my release pipeline variable shared and exposed correctly. Now, my next issue is to do with a failing PATCH. Is this a bug?

```
              - task: PowerShell@2
                condition: and(succeeded(), not(canceled()))
                name: RetainOnSuccess
                displayName: Retain on Success
                inputs:
                  failOnStderr: true
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    $contentType = "application/json";
                    $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
                    $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 100; protectPipeline = false; };
                    $request = ConvertTo-Json @($rawRequest);
                    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/testing-ci/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/$(myVarfromStage)?api-version=7.1-preview.2";
                    Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method PATCH -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
```

I get the following error out of devops

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'D:\a\_temp\6ee1c3fd-e406-417e-bf9f-d860a21d1647.ps1'"
##[error]Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The retention lease update is 
null.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.WebApi.RetentionLeaseUpdateIsNull, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build2.WebApi","typeKey":"RetentionLeaseUpdateIsNull","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At D:\a\_temp\6ee1c3fd-e406-417e-bf9f-d860a21d1647.ps1:8 char:1
+ Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method PATCH -Headers $headers -ContentT ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc 
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
```

My PATCH request looks right?

Answer (score 0):

From your script, you need to modify as below:

Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method **POST** -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;

So the sample should be:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
                condition: and(succeeded(), not(canceled()))
                name: RetainOnSuccess
                displayName: Retain on Success
                inputs:
                  failOnStderr: true
                  targetType: 'inline'
                  script: |
                    $contentType = "application/json";
                    $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
                    $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 100; protectPipeline = false; };
                    $request = ConvertTo-Json @($rawRequest);
                    $uri = "https://dev.azure.com/testing-ci/$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/$(myVarfromStage)?api-version=7.1-preview.2";
                    Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method POST -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
```

Comment: I've already set a Retention, the request thats failing is a PATCH to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

ConvertTo-Json ($rawRequest)

Instead of:

Use ConvertTo-Json @($rawRequest)

The code sample from MS is not correct. Maybe it was correct on the preview version but not for version 7.0.
The request body needs to be a single object therefore you need to remove the array operator.

Below is a working version for API Version: 7.0.

```
 - task: PowerShell@2
    condition: and(succeeded(), not(canceled()))
    name: RetainOnSuccess
    displayName: Retain on Success
    inputs:
      failOnStderr: true
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
        $contentType = "application/json";
        $headers = @{ Authorization = 'Bearer $(System.AccessToken)' };
        $rawRequest = @{ daysValid = 365; protectPipeline = $false};
        $request = ConvertTo-Json $rawRequest;
        $uri = "$(System.CollectionUri)$(System.TeamProject)/_apis/build/retention/leases/$(newLeaseId)?api-version=7.0";
        Invoke-RestMethod -uri $uri -method PATCH -Headers $headers -ContentType $contentType -Body $request;
```